# Reduction of a scheme is homeomorphic to the scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the definition of the reduction of a scheme.

On the notes it is defined as $X_{red}=V(\mathcal N_X)$ where:

$V(\mathcal N_X)= \{ x\in X$ s.t. $V(\mathcal N_{X,x})\neq \mathcal O_{X,x}\} $ and

$\mathcal N_X(U)=\{s \in \mathcal O_{X,x}$ s.t. $s_x $ is nilradical in $\mathcal O_{X,x} \}$

It says then that it's homeomorphic to $X$. How can be proved it?

Comment: Hint: What is the intersection of all prime ideals?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640899/reduced-scheme-x-red-out-of-a-scheme-x/